# CMake Error on linux (Flutter project in Android Studio)

Tags: android, linux, flutter, cmake

When I create a new **Flutter project in Android Studio** (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1), I build an APK and run it on the android emulator with no problem, but when I try to run it on linux I get this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:48 (message):
    Could not find compiler set in environment variable CXX:
    clang++.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

My system (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS) doesn't have that version of CMake installed, it has /usr/share/cmake-3.22 installed

And in Android Studio settings, under System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools, CMake 3.22.1 is installed

I am not able to figure out how to adjust the CMake version in Android Studio and what is the correct solution. Please any ideas?

Comment: CMake seems to complain about not being able to find `clang++` compiler in the system. You could whether install `clang++` or set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to an available compiler (e.g. `g++`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On my system these packages are already installed: clang and clang-14

Comment: Can you execute `clang++` from a command line?

Comment: I have been able to verify:
clang test.cc ... OK
g++ hello.cpp -o hello ...OK

But:
clang++ hello.cpp -o hello
hello.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

I don't know if it is a correct way to run it in the terminal? When I type clang, the console displays these hints: clang clang++ clang++-14 clang-14 clang-cpp-14

Comment: [✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.22.1
    • ninja version 1.10.1
    • pkg-config version 0.29.2

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED!

In the **CMakeKists.txt** file (in the /linux folder) I have added at the beginning (I think it has to be before the *project(runner LANGUAGES CXX)* line):

`set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")`

Now it runs on linux with no problems.

EDIT (best solution):

```
sudo apt install lib32stdc++-12-dev
```

Comment: It may be better to specify just `g++`, and not rely on where the binary lives, especially if you intend to run CMake on a different system.

Comment: Oh, and how can I do it?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")` should work.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package lib32stdc++-12-dev

Comment: I'm using fedora and It didn't solve my problem either, unable to locate package and same error after set line adding